# Parse results of a "dig" bulk query

Tags: text-processing, dig

We use a security rating service which among other things, searches the world for imposter domains  that resemble our domains. So it does find some of those but also finds ones that don't exist. It finds a lot of them.

- In the 5th line of a `dig` response, there is the term `Answer:`  then a number.
- I would like to run `dig` with a text file of hostnames, and for the results to be two columns only:

  Column 1: the hostname for that row

  Column 2: either `Answer: x` or just `x`, the value of `Answer`.

So far I can run `dig` with a bulk input file, but can't figure out how to filter the results and get them to display like that.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Comment: Are you sure that your methodology is sound? Because I would assume that a professional service would not present you a list with domains that don't exist. -|- Running `dig [some typo domain]` is a request for the `A` record of the apex of that domain. And for example that will not result in an answer from a domain that is genuinely  registered, but for which the owner has not has simply not set up that apex A record or no DNS at all.  -|-  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1780598/2952385

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `dig hostname +short` to get answer in one line and also when you do bulk dig remember to use sleep between iterations else you might be get temporary blocked/rate limited from Nameserver.
Here is the full one liner that might help you out

```
 cat input_file | while read -r line; do ans=$(dig $line +short); echo "$line $ans"; sleep 3; done
```

I did not get what you want exactly  but you can post an example or use grep command in above line as per your need.